# Can I use a colon at the end of an incomplete sentence (see two example)?

Tags: colons

Thank you for your help. Examples are provided below.

Example A.

> Some people feel they must...:
>
> 1. Prove their worth all the time.
> 2. Put others down all the time.

Example B.

> The pairings were as follows:
>
> Women:
>
> Janet: Alone, and with Phil.
>
> Karla: Alone, with Phil, and with two random research assistants.
>
> Men:
>
> John: Alone.
>
> Tom: Alone, with John, and with two random research assistants.

Comment: It gets very messy. You're much better using differently indented bullet format for lists within lists, and an ellipsis alone (followed by non-capitalised fragments) in the first example.

Comment: Unrelated to the punctuation, it seems strange to describe a person alone as a "pairing". And does "Karla with two random research assistants" mean Karla with both assistants at the same time, or two separate pairings? Unclear.

Comment: thanks for your replies, especially Edwin.